# How to remove the edittext cursor blinking?

Tags: android, android-edittext

I am facing the issue in edittext, i have four edittext and a spinner in my activity in that when the activity is viewed , the automatically the blinking cursor is blinking in the third edittext of my activity.How to remove the automatic blinking in edittext and to make blinking cursor should be visible when the edittext clicked.And also answer why this issue is occurring.

The below layout is the activity_main.xml

```
 <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp">


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/textinput">

    <Spinner
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:id="@+id/spinner2"
        android:text="@string/inheritance"
        android:prompt="@string/inheritance"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:popupBackground="@drawable/textinput"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:hint="@string/location"
        android:ems="10"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:id="@+id/yourLocation_editText"
        android:background="@drawable/textinput"
        android:typeface="sans" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:hint="@string/scammer_location"
        android:ems="10"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:id="@+id/editText7"
        android:layout_below="@+id/yourLocation_editText"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/textinput"
        android:typeface="sans"/>

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:hint="@string/keyWord"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/editText8"
        android:background="@drawable/textinput"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText7"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:typeface="sans"/>

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:inputType="phone"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/phoneNumber_editText"
        android:hint="@string/phonenumber"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:background="@drawable/textinput"
        android:layout_above="@+id/yourLocation_editText"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:typeface="sans"/>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Can you add HTML what the result is and what do you expect to get?

Comment: This question is obviously not a duplicate of the referenced question. While the former is about the cursor in an ANDROID `EditText`, the latter is about forms in HTML and Lavarel.